# How to properly use GridLayout to position elements in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, grid, textarea, grid-layout

This is what I want my JFrame to look like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|Play                                                                     - 0 x |
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Score List:     | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Mario: 100      | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Luigi: 50       |        
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Waluigi: 20     | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Wario: 10       |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |    
|Status: Ready!                                                       Score: 30 |
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

At the moment, each element is of equal size and basically just split up the middle and top/bottom. Play is the title of the Frame, the %s represent a JPanel in which the user can play a game. The 'Status: Ready' is a JLabel, as is the 'Score: 30'. The list of scores is a JTextArea.

So, how do I set the sizes and positions of these elements? I'll give you my code so far, perhaps you could tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
this.add(playPanel);
this.add(scoreArea);
this.add(statusLabel);
this.add(scoreLabel);
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
```

Comment: posted ASCII art talking about BorderLayout

Comment: I cannot see how one would achieve that layout using a `GridLayout`.  I'd instead look to a [Nested Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) or perhaps a `GridBagLayout` or `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

[`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) should be the perfect solution for you. With it's support of obeying preferred size of component and clever use of `GridBagConstraints`. using `GridBagLayout's GridBagConstraint` property:

1. **`gridx, gridy`**: your component will be placed in `grid(X, Y)`. Before adding any component you specify the grid using these property, to which component will be added.
2. **`anchor`**: `FIRST_LINE_START, PAGE_START, FIRST_LINE_END,
   LINE_START, LINE_END` etc are used to orient the component in the
   available space of each grid.
3. **`weightx, weighty`**: For `it is the center` label `weightx` and `weighty` are specified to respond with re-sizing the container in `width` and `height`. For `score list` label, only `weighty` is specified to respond with re-sizing the container only in `height`.
4. **`gridwidth`**: For `it is the center` label this property was specified as `2` to take two grid.
5. **fill**: is specified as `BOTH` for the `it is the center` label to fill the available display are in both width and height. And this property is set as `VERTICAL` for `score list` label to fill the display area in height.

**Here is a Demo built for you to give you the idea at first glance:**

Not really coded as standard(*such as setting preferred size by `setPreferredSize()` should not be done*) but i think it meets the demo purpose.

[image]

**Source code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Rashed
 */
 class GridBagLayoutDemo extends JFrame{


    public JLabel createLabel(String txt, int width, int height, Color color)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(txt);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        return label;
    }

    public GridBagLayoutDemo() throws HeadlessException {
       setSize(400,400);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
       GridBagConstraints labCnst = new GridBagConstraints();

       labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
       labCnst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
       labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
       labCnst.gridx  = 0;
       labCnst.gridy = 0;
       panel.add(createLabel("play", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

      // labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
       labCnst.gridx  = 0;
       labCnst.gridy = 2;
       panel.add(createLabel("Status: Ready!", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

       labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
       labCnst.gridx  = 2;
       labCnst.gridy = 0;
       panel.add(createLabel("-0x", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

       labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
       labCnst.gridx  = 2;
       labCnst.gridy = 2;
       panel.add(createLabel("score:30", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);


       labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
       labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
       labCnst.gridx  = 2;
       labCnst.gridy = 1;
       labCnst.gridwidth = 1;

       labCnst.weightx = 0.7;
       labCnst.weighty = 0.7;
       panel.add(createLabel("ScoreList", 100, 200, new Color(0xFFAA00)), labCnst);


       labCnst.gridx = 0;
       labCnst.gridy = 1;
       //labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LIN;
       labCnst.gridwidth = 2;

       labCnst.weightx = 0.8;
       labCnst.weighty = 0.8;
       labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
       panel.add(createLabel("It is the center", 200, 200, new Color(0xFFD47E)), labCnst);

       //labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;


       add(panel);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at a [Gridbaglayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead. 
It might better suit your needs.